# Coldfusion - Add checkbox to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, checkbox, coldfusion, cfml

I am trying to find out if and how it is possible to create an Excel spreadsheet and add a checkbox as a field.  I have created a spreadsheet using the spreadsheet tags already but would like to add this extra field.
Any help would be great..

Thank You

Comment: 1.) _"..it is possible to create an Excel spreadsheet..."_ **Open Excel, Click Blank Workbook**.. 2.) _"...add a checkbox..."_ **Developer Tab > Insert > Check box**.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, The OP is looking to accomplish this with ColdFusion programming code.

Comment: @DanBracuk This question will be closed soon anyway. If the quality of the question was better, so would my answer :-)

Comment: I think the answer is that it's not possible, but, somebody else might know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Other than asking a general question that is simple and fairly self explanatory.  It’s does say cold fusion so anyone can comprehend easily.  If you chose not to read than don’t complain about the quality.

Comment: It's not possible with with CF or what it uses for spreadsheets, POI. You'll need to use something else. If you're new to S.O. please see [Ask].

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a checkbox to a spreadsheet, you need to add VB code to it. (making it excel-only, aka won't work on google docs)

It would be much easier to use true/false for column value.